# Where are GRID algorithms in SAGA 2.1.4?

Tags: saga

I am a real newbie on QGIS and wanting to draw contour maps from satellite, following the youtube videos.  So now I have a table with all data, and following the video, I should use the SAGA tool GRID (natural neighbour) tool but can't find it on the toolbox.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the simplified interface in Processing toolbox as you can see in the red box below:

[image]

You need to change it yo advanced interface, and you find SAGA tools as well as other tools, but you mau need to install the other tools separately:

[image]

If turning the interface from simple to advance didn't solve your problem, then make sure that SAGA installed in your system. You can have a look at [how to configure external tools in QGIS](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#a-note-for-windows-users) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot. somehow to button to select the type of interface does not show. however, by typing the search for "grid" some grid options show. I will try to follow that...

Comment: I can confirm that the "advanced interface"/"simplified interface" do not show... option

Comment: Try to install QGIS from OSGeo4W from http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html. There are 32 bit and 64 bit. You can choose the express desktop installation and follow the steps. Then, see if reinstalling QGIS fixes the processing toolbar.

Comment: It took me quite a while as I was absent, in Africa, in a project, and just came out. The SAGA tools now appear with the heading (SAGA 2.1.4 235  algortihms.

Comment: It took me quite a while as I was absent, in Africa, in a project, and just came out. However in spite many saga tools show (its version 2.1.4) the grid algorithms do not show

Comment: Do you have the `Raster tools` instead?